# Is it a good practice to create lots of jobs in a flink cluster?

Tags: apache-flink

I am planning to create a rule engine with flink streaming.

There are some requirements on the execution :

- All events to be executed against the rule set must be read from kafka.
- All rules must be executed in a limited lapse of time.

The problem is that a rule can be added at runtime, so I can't simply create lots of jobs to handle all incoming messages because I risk to exceed the maximum time allowing to execute the rules.

I have the assurance that a single rule can be executed under the time limit.

*So I wonder if it's a good practice to create one job by rule and add more jobs when new rules are coming ? (this may be hundred of rules).*

I have the intuition that this is not the way to handle the problem but nothing really rational to explain why.

A second approach would be to maintain a queue (in zookeeper for example) to keep a trace about which rule has been executed against which event. So the work of each job only consist to :

- pick a rule in the queue
- execute it against the event
- do it again until all rules have been executed against the event

Comment: You could also use a CEP engine and integrate that into Flink.

Comment: @goodie If I understand correctly, with CEP engine I'll not be able to dynamically add new rules in my job. 
Because the execution graph is built when the job is executed and cannot be modified after that

Comment: All CEP engines that I know allow adding/managing rules at runtime. I think that is the whole point of being a CEP engine. In Esper you do it with "epAdministrator.createEPL(...)".

Comment: @goodie I didn't find anything about add a new pattern in Flink CEP (at runtime). Do you have a pointer to help me ?

Comment: I think Flink CEP is really just a small canned operator and lacks this functions. Other CEP engines can do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to dynamically adapt your program logic you can use the co-flatmap operator. The co-flatmap operator has two inputs, one would be the normal event input and the other one would be the rule input. Internally you will store the rules and apply them to incoming events from the other input.

The following could look like:

```java
DataStream<Input> input = ...
DataStream<Rule> rules = ...

input
  .connect(rules)
  .keyBy(keySelector1, keySelector2)
  .flatMap(new MyCoFlatMap());

public static class MyCoFlatMap implements CoFlatMapFunction<Input, Rule, Output> {

    @Override
    public void flatMap1(Input input, Collector<Output> collector) throws Exception {
        // process input
    }

    @Override
    public void flatMap2(Rule rule, Collector<Output> collector) throws Exception {
        // store rules
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll try that as soon as possible